# Zoom controls not showing when using a MapView with fill_parent

Tags: android, google-maps

Hey everyone I am working on an applications and I am using the built in zoom controls. When using a specific size I can see the zoom controls. When using fill_parent the zoom controls are not visible. How it is setup is a mapview inside of a frame layout(also using fill parent for the height and width but with an offset down the screen. The only thing I can think of is the fill parent issue is with the framelayout and the zoom controls are off the screen. Sorry if this is confusing, I confused myself writing it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Post the layout xml. Does it work with the Mapview just in a Linear Layout? Why do you want the Frame Layout?

Comment: this is the code that I switched and made it work. the issue was with the frame layout and fill parent when doing that it caused the screen to go outside of the visible range. If there is a better way of doing this please let me know. I don't know XML at all and this is all new to me. (abbreviated code below)

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="300px"
    android:layout_height="300px"
android:layout_x="0px"
android:layout_y="100px"
>
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>

</FrameLayout>

Comment: and that did not format the code at all. Sorry about that. Basically I  figured out the issue but I don't understand why fill parent doesn't compensate for the shift down

Answer (score 5):

Had a similar issue while trying to get the zoom controls working on my app.

Discovered that the layout for the MapView MUST be set to "clickable" in order for the zoom controls to show up and be functional.  They don't even show if the map's not clickable

Here's a simple layout from Android SDK site that shows the tag in the layout.

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="Your Maps API Key" />
```

After putting that tag into the layout, everything worked correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ZoomControls  like this.

```
ZoomControls mapZoomControl = (ZoomControls) findViewById(R.id.zcMapZoomControl);
mapZoomControl.setOnZoomInClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myMap.getController().zoomIn();
        }
});
    mapZoomControl.setOnZoomOutClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myMap.getController().zoomOut();
        }
});
```